# Apache error: "File does not exist" (Not telling me when which file)

Tags: apache

I'm having a Joomla/ Server related issue, when I try to access a Module I get the error below. I've checked in my Apache error log, and seen the Apache error. My issue is that, it doesn't even let me know which file it can't find.

```
An error has occurred.

Joomla Error : 500 View not found [name, type, prefix]: default, html, roksprocketView 
Apache Error : [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/templates, referer: http://localhost:8888/Joomla/final_GKFG/
```

How can I locate the file causing the error?

Comment: You asked this [exact same question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694719/apache-error-file-does-not-exist-not-telling-me-when-which-file) simultaneously, cross-posting is usually not recommended.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Hey Johan, I've deleted the question posted on SO

Comment: Great. And welcome to Joomla StackExchange. Have you found a solution to your question? If not, feel free to comment on the suggested answers, or edit your question with any additional information.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look into the RokSprocket module. Make sure both Joomla and RokSprocket is up to date, and other extensions as well.

If everything is up to date, try reinstalling RokSprocket.

The [RocketTheme forum](http://www.rockettheme.com/forum) might also be able to help

Answer (score 1):

Since the error message is generated by Joomla, it's not an Apache error.

Joomla reports that the requested view was not found. When an Url request is received, it's routed to the right component (view), and the rest of the associated modules are shown.

If there's any misconfiguration in the generated Url, you get: Joomla Error : 500 View not found [name, type, prefix]: ....